# tidyr quasiquotation with lexical scoping

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

I realize that tidy evaluation does not use lexical scoping, but I want the quasiquotation in `rlang` to look for symbols in the environment I decide.

Current behavior:

```
envir <- new.env(parent = globalenv())
eval(parse(text = "little_b <- 'b'"), envir = envir)
eval(rlang::expr(!!little_b), envir = envir)

## Error in (function (x)  : object 'little_b' not found
```

Instead, I want the last line to return `"b"`. Bonus points if you find a version of `eval()` that does the job here AND works like `evaluate::try_capture_stack()`.

FYI: I am trying to solve [this issue](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/200#issuecomment-361502398).

Comment: tidyeval is all about lexical scoping ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `with` to pass the expression within an environment

```
with(envir, expr(!!little_b))
#[1] "b"
```

Or another option is `local`

```
local(rlang::expr(!!little_b), envir = envir)
#[1] "b"
```

---

Or pass via `quote` in `eval` (as @lionel mentioned)

```
eval(quote(expr = rlang::expr(!! little_b)), envir = envir)
#[1] "b"
```

Comment: The last example should be `quote()` instead of `substitute()` since you're not doing any substitution.